# "If the task is already running..." setting in Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: windows, windows-task-scheduler, windows-server

Let's say I have a Windows Console executable MyApp.exe

It can take different command line parameters and depending on parameters can perform different functions.

`MyApp.exe /1` will execute Function1 that takes 30 minutes to complete

`MyApp.exe /2` will execute Function2 that takes 20 minutes to complete

I then configure `MyApp.exe /1` in Windows Task Scheduler to run daily at 2PM. I specify "Do Not Start a new Instance" (default value) in Task Settings.

I then configure `MyApp.exe /2` (executable is at the same location as above) in Windows Task Scheduler to run daily at 2:10PM. I specify "Do Not Start a new Instance" (default value) in Task Settings.

Will `MyApp.exe /2` execute? Is "Do Not Start a new Instance" truly per task (in which case I expect `MyApp.exe /2` to execute) or per process (in which case I expect `MyApp.exe /2` not to execute)?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see what happens?

Answer (score 0):

The
[Help](https://winintro.ru/taskscheduler.en/html/d758ff5d-27d3-4090-b1c2-14ecaa83ff12.htm)
says:

> **Do not start a new instance**: The Task Scheduler service will not run the new instance of the task and will not stop the instance that is already running.

This is about the scheduled task itself, not about what it does.
So, as in your case you have *two different tasks*, although they run
the same executable, both will execute in parallel starting at 2:10PM.